# How do I reference a page written as react component in the sidebar?

Tags: docusaurus

The docusaurus documentation describes how to create a custom page as a react component.

It also describes how to add this page to the headerLinks section.
So give the custom page 'custom-page.js', I can add it to the headerLinks like so:

```
const siteConfig = {
    headerLinks: [
        {
            page: 'custom-page',
            label: 'My Custom Page'
        }
    ]
}
```

Great - that works! 
But how for the love of god do I add that page to the sidebar configuration? I couldn't fin anything in the docs regarding that, and all attempts to reference the page have failed.
Is it because it does not have an id? How could I give a react component page an id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docusaurus maintainer here! Unfortunately, there's no way to accomplish this now as users do not have much control over the rendering of the sidebar, only the contents. That'll change in future in [v2](https://github.com/facebook/Docusaurus/issues/789), so stay tuned.